# break an equation

Tags: equations

I need to break a long equation in my beamer presentation. My code is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ABC}
\framesubtitle{DEF}
\begin{itemize}
\item this equation
\begin{equation}
V_{t}(K_{t},EF_{t}^{(s)})=\max\limits_{\left\{ I_{\tau }\right\} _{\tau
=0}^{\infty }}E\left\{ \sum_{\tau =0}^{\infty }\beta ^{\tau }\left[ \pi
(K_{t+\tau },EF_{t+\tau }^{(r)})-I_{t+\tau }-C(I_{t+\tau },EF_{t+\tau
}^{(s)})\right] |\Omega _{t}^{(r)}\right\} ,  \tag{11}
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I tried eqnarray and multline but I always get an error message. Can someone help me.

Best

Dario

Comment: If you alway get an error message, then why don't you quote that message so we could know as well. In any case forget you ever heard about `eqnarray ` and use `align ` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked great for me:

```
\begin{align}
    V_{t}(K_{t},EF_{t}^{(s)})=&\max\limits_{\left\{ I_{\tau }\right\} _{\tau
        =0}^{\infty }}E\left\{ \sum_{\tau =0}^{\infty }\beta ^{\tau }\left[ \pi
        (K_{t+\tau },EF_{t+\tau }^{(r)})\right.\right.\nonumber\\
        &\left.\left.-I_{t+\tau }-C(I_{t+\tau },EF_{t+\tau
            }^{(s)})\right] |\Omega _{t}^{(r)}\right\} ,  \tag{11}
\end{align}
```

I had to place some `\left.` and `\right.` before and after the linebreak, because braces have to close in the same line they were opened. But in this case you probably should set the size of the braces manually anyway so that the matching braces are of the same size.

The position of the linebreak isn't optimal, you have to figure out how you like it the most.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Now I will refine the points you suggested.